# How to store webcam captured image path in mysql database using php.?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to capture image from webcam user image that image stored in specified folder and captured image path store into mysql using php. I have an problem with webcam captured image path is not stored in mysql database. so please help me...

**JS**

```js
 <script src="js/webscript.js"></script>

     <!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/webcam.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
     
     <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
     <script language="JavaScript">
      Webcam.set({
       width: 320,
       height: 240,
       image_format: 'jpeg',
       jpeg_quality: 90
      });
      Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
      
      var shutter = new Audio();
      shutter.autoplay = false;
      shutter.src = navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox/) ? 'shutter.ogg' : 'shutter.mp3';
      
      function take_snapshot() {
       // take snapshot and get image data
       Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
        // display results in page
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
         '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
         '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
         Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'upload.php', function(code, text) {
          alert(data_uri);
         });
       } );
      }
      
     </script>
```

```css
**PHP**

    <?php
     include 'connection.php';   
      
        $path = 'uploads/webcam'.date('YmdHis').rand(383,1000).'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], $path);
        $query = "INSERT INTO entry(name) VALUES('".$path."')";
        mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
 
    ?>

**HTML**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Javascript Webcam</title>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"> 
     <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
     <div id="my_camera"></div>
     <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
     <form>
      <input type=button class="btn btn-success" value="Take Snapshot" name="sub" onClick="take_snapshot()">
     </form>
     <div id="results" class="well">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </center>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your PHP code? are you sure `$_FILES['webcam']` contains something? what about `$_GET['url']`?

Comment: i have tried $_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'] instead of $_GET['url'].

Comment: Ok. However, does `$_FILES['webcam']` contain something? are you getting an error? please tell us more about your problem :)

Comment: when i capture image that image stored in folder but my insert query is not excuted.

Comment: You should be getting the mysql_error or you should display the alert. What is happening? More details please...

Comment: not getting any alert or mysql error message.

Comment: Could you set `$result = mysql_query($query);` and then tell us what the $result variable contains?

Comment: $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
echo "<script>alert('".$result."');</script>";  sql query not excuted still..

Comment: Ninir i got the solution...

Comment: Could you share it so that this ticket is resolved? :)

Comment: this code working without error..

Comment: Congratz ;)! What did you change exactly? (so that other people facing the issue can resolve it too)

Comment: ninir i have some problem with it is that when i captured image that image should be with his customer name. eg. when i filled registration form that time i am capturing image but that name will with image name saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

javascript function
 Webcam.set({
        width: 260,
        height: 260,
        image_format: 'jpeg',
        jpeg_quality: 90,
        force_flash: false
    });
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );

```
function take_snapshot() {

    // take snapshot and get image data
    Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
        // display results in page

        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML =
            '<h3>Here is your image....</h3>' +
            '<img src="' +data_uri+ '" width=\'280px\' height=\'250px\'/>';

        Webcam.upload(data_uri, 'saveimages.php', function (code, text) {

                alert(data_uri);
        });
    });
    Webcam.reset();
}
```

php function:
 require_once 'core/init.php';

```
$path = 'images/saved_images/webcam'.date('YmdHis').rand(383,1000).'.jpg';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], $path);
$query = "INSERT INTO trial(image) VALUES('".$path."')";
$db->query($query);
echo "<script>alert('successfully..');</script>";
```

html:
 
                 Take A Picture